# how to check whether a var is string or number using javascript

Tags: javascript, typeof

I have a variable `var number="1234"`, though the number is a numeric value but it is between `""` so when I check it using `typeof` or by `NaN` I got it as a string .

```
function test()
{
    var number="1234"

if(typeof(number)=="string")
{
    alert("string");
}
if(typeof(number)=="number")
{
    alert("number");
}

}
```

I got always `alert("string")`, can you please tell me how can I check if this is a number?

Comment: since you are storing it with "" it will be string only.
you need to give var number = 12345

Comment: Have a look at the functions defined in this answer - 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line

```
 var number = "1234";
```

creates a new String object with the value "1234". By putting the value in quotes, you are saying that it a string.

If you want to check if a string only contains numeric digits, you can use [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/regexp).

```
if (number.match(/^-?\d+$/)) {
    alert("It's a whole number!");
} else if (number.match(/^-?\d+*\.\d+$/)) {
    alert("It's a decimal number!");
}
```

The pattern `/^\d+$/` means: at the start (`^`) of the string, there is an optional minus sign (`-?`), then a digit (`\d`), followed by any more digits (`+`), and then the end of the string (`$`). The other pattern just looks for a point between the groups of digits.

Comment: That will work provided the value is only digits, any other value (such as -1 or 1.5) will return false. A robust *isNumber()* function has been posted in response to [Validate numbers in JavaScript - IsNumeric()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric/1830844#1830844).

Answer (score 8):

As far I understand your question you are asking for a test to
detect if a string represents a numeric value.

A quick test should be

```
function test() {
   var number="1234"
   return (number==Number(number))?"number":"string"
}
```

As Number, if called without the `new` keyword convert the string into a number. 
If the variable content is untouched (`==` will cast back the numeric value to a string)
you are dealing with a number. It is a string otherwise.

```
function isNumeric(value) {
   return (value==Number(value))?"number":"string"
}

/* tests evaluating true */
console.log(isNumeric("1234"));  //integer
console.log(isNumeric("1.234")); // float
console.log(isNumeric("12.34e+1")); // scientific notation
console.log(isNumeric(12));     // Integer
console.log(isNumeric(12.7));   // Float
console.log(isNumeric("0x12")); // hex number

/* tests evaluating false */
console.log(isNumeric("1234e"));
console.log(isNumeric("1,234"));
console.log(isNumeric("12.34b+1"));
console.log(isNumeric("x"));
```

Comment: Fails where value is empty string or whitespace as both convert to 0 and `0 == ''`.

Answer (score 2):

See [parseInt and parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Functions#parseInt_and_parseFloat_Functions)

Comment: using parseInt , it converts both "abcd" and "1234" to a integer. which gives me wrong result. i want only "1234" to be converted into inumeric value

Comment: @Romi, actually the "numeric" value of 'romi' is NaN (not a number). Perhaps you should check if the resultant variable isNaN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

Answer (score 0):

because `var number="1234"` is a string. the double quotes makes it a literal.

if you want a number use it like this

```
var number = 1234;
```

Update:

If you are taking the input from a input tag forexample, the dataType will be string, if you want to convert it to a number, you can use the parseInt() function

```
var number = "1234";

var newNumber = parseInt(number);

alert(typeof newNumber); // will result in string
```

Comment: Ibu: Ya absolutely, but what my problem is i ma getting through it a text box from where i am getting "1234" how can i remove "" to make it a number. although when i put alert on the data i got from text box i get it as 1234 but while checking it gives me a string

Comment: See my update @Romi, using parseInt() for integers or parseFloat() for decimal numbers will help fix this problem

Comment: Fails where the input has trailing non-number characters.

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to a number then compare it to the original string.

```
if ( parseFloat(the_string,10) == the_string ) {
    // It is a string containing a number (and only a number)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way:

```
var num_value = +value;
if(value !== '' && !isNaN(num_value)) {
    // the string contains (is) a number
}
```

Comment: empty string converts to zero, so `!isNaN(+(''))` gives false. Also whitespace and *null* convert to zero too, so they will return true (though in this case null is not an expected value).

Comment: I think the simplest is: `function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}` posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric/1830844#1830844).